# mysql user table

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL.

I run an update statement against the table `user` to change password of the `root` user. Here is how the first row  looks when I query `select * from user`:

```
| localhost          | root             | sam
```

My first question is why password isn't encrypted.

Secondly, when I'm trying to login

```
mysql -u root -p
```

using the same password it responds

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 1):

Don't play around with system tables.
If you want to change the password use [SET PASSWORD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html)